# Will an image or document be cached when it is viewed through UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

Typically when we load a image or document through a browser, the image gets cached in a temp folder. Is this the same case for Mobile safari and other browsers in MObile?

And if that is the case, if the phone is rooted, will user be able to access  them?
Will an image or document be cached when it is viewed through UIWebView in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the class doing the caching is NSURLRequest. You can remove the cache for a particular request

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

or for all of them

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

or set an empty cache before performing any request

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm it.The cache contents in any ways should be stored at some location, and before we programmtically clear the cache user can access it from the location. Is this possible?

Comment: If you set an empty cache before performing the request (as outlined in the answer) there is nothing to access. If you don't, then yes, it is possible.